# Instantly posting a post in facebook when added to a website. Facebook API

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-authentication

Okay, so, I have a facebook page. I am currently building a website and I want my users to upload something like posts in the website, with photos, info, etc. The thing is, I want when a user has uploaded something and the new page has been created with the info, I want to write some code and make the post instantly posted on the facebook page. Basically I want to remove the person, who is going to be an admin of the page and make him/ her manually post the new content on the facebook page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a rough idea of the approach you may be able to use:

You will need to [create a Facebook app](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/register#create-app) and integrate [login with Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login). The login scope should include `manage_pages` and `publish_pages` [permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.5).

Once you login after granting these permissions, make a GET call to `/me/accounts` which will give you page ids and access tokens of the pages you admin. Short-lived access tokens can be [exchanged](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension) for long lived ones which can then be used to make subsequent calls. Remember you can only use these permissions without approval if you are an admin/developer of the app.

Use that page access token to make a [POST request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/page/feed#publish) to `/{page-id}/feed` with the `message` or `link` param set to the link to your website's URL.

How you trigger the POST action is up to you.